# Contribution Report - Grouped by Custom Field

Tags: civireport, custom-reports

I am looking to be able to build a report that essentially has aggregate donations grouped by a custom field.  For example - every donor is asked: How did you hear about us (Referral Source), which is answered via a contribution custom field set of options.  Essentially we want to create a report that says:

Referral Source - Number of Donations - Total Donations - Average Donations

Is there a report that can let me do that - is there an extension that provides such a capability?

Comment: You could look at extending Summary Fields https://civicrm.org/extensions/summary-fields

Comment: You could do it in search kit I think

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this via a contribution summary report - unfortunately that does not allow for sorting.